# How can I use TF's `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe` for one-hot encoded output?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm trying to train a model with input shape (227, 227, 3) and output shape (23,) and softmax as activation function. I'm trying to use [`flow_from_dataframe`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_dataframe) as follows:

```py
 train_data_generator = idg.flow_from_dataframe(
     dataframe=training_data,
     x_col="image_name",
     y_col="age",
     class_mode="categorical",
     shuffle=True,
     target_size=(227, 227),
 )
```

My df looks like this:

```
                                     image_name                                              age
0      /home/.../data/age/077/588.png            [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]'
```

I've also tried `class_mode="raw"` with no success. How should I transform my data so I can train using `flow_from_dataframe`?

Answer (score 0):

According to your output error message, the `age` column of your dataframe is a string, not a list as it appears you want. To use `flow_from_directory` you can convert that column to a list (instead of strings) something like this:

```py
df['age'].apply(lambda val: [int(item) for item in str_val.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split()])
```